# How can I get the size of a C object in Rust

Tags: rust, ffi

bindgen has nicely given me

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn Hacl_Bignum4096_new_bn_from_bytes_be(len: u32, b: *mut u8) -> *mut u64;
}
```

returning something of type `*mut u64`. Unfortunately there is no reliable way (that I have found) to determine how many u64s are allocated. This makes is very hard (for me) to extract the data pointed to into something I can safely persist in a Rust struct instance.

As a consequence, any time I want to use any function from the Hacl library I have to perform that conversion and free up the created pointers in an unsafe block.

```rust
impl Bignum {
    /// Returns true if self < other
    pub fn lt(&self, other: &Bignum) -> Result<bool, Error> {
        
        let hacl_result: HaclBnWord;
        unsafe {
            let a = self.get_hacl_bn()?;
            let b = other.get_hacl_bn()?;
            hacl_result = Hacl_Bignum4096_lt_mask(a, b);
            free_hacl_bn(a);
            free_hacl_bn(b);
        }
        Ok(hacl_result != 0 as HaclBnWord)
    }
}
```

`unsafe fn get_hacl_bn(&self)` is suitably defined and calls `Hacl_Bignum4096_new_bn_from_bytes_be()` appropriately. And `unsafe fn free_hacl_bn(bn: HaclBnType)` also lives in this module.

I haven't benchmarked anything yet, but having to perform the conversion to a Hacl_Bignum from bytes each and every time feels wasteful.

So is there a way to determine the size of what is pointed to or is there a way to copy the data out of it into something safe?

Comment: Generally no, you cannot determine the size of an array by only a pointer. You can look at surrounding documentation to see if the length is evident by the parameters passed, or perhaps there's another function that might get or calculate a length for you. (maybe you aren't supposed to know and the pointer is only used as a "handle" to be provided to other functions)

Comment: @kmdreko, thank you. In this case the surrounding documentation lied, suggesting a fixed size. Only after debugging crashes in a debugger did I see it was lying. Oh, well.

Comment: [This readme](https://github.com/project-everest/hacl-star/tree/master/code/bignum) says *"In our library, in order to achieve a constant-time implementation, the length of bignum is always limited, for example, with a modulus size"*. I would wager that the `Bignum4096`-class of function always use a fixed length of 64 `u64`s.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate

Comment: Yeah. It very strongly implied that there were 64 u64s, and I had built on that assumption. Until I started getting runtime errors about trying to deallocate memory that had never been allocated when the lifetime of my structure ended. Creating a slice from a raw pointer really produces odd results when you tell it that the source length is larger than it really is.

Comment: Note that this question appears to be completely unrelated to Rust. You also can't determine the size of the allocation in C, and if you could, you could use the same approach in Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write: "having to perform the conversion to a Hacl_Bignum from bytes each and every time feels wasteful". It seems like you are not letting the library do its job. You should not keep a copy of the bignum data in your Rust struct `Bignum`, but only the pointer you get from the library. Something like:

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn Hacl_Bignum4096_new_bn_from_bytes_be(len: u32, b: *mut u8) -> *mut u64;
    pub fn Hacl_Bignum4096_lt_mask(a: *mut u64, b: *mut u64) -> u64;
}

struct Bignum {
    handle: *mut u64,
}

struct BignumError {}

impl Bignum {
    pub fn new(bytes: &mut [u8]) -> Result<Self, BignumError> {
        unsafe {
            let handle =
                Hacl_Bignum4096_new_bn_from_bytes_be(bytes.len() as u32, bytes.as_mut_ptr());
            if handle.is_null() {
                return Err(BignumError {});
            } else {
                Ok(Self { handle })
            }
        }
    }

    /// Returns true if self < other
    pub fn lt(&self, other: &Bignum) -> bool {
        unsafe { Hacl_Bignum4096_lt_mask(self.handle, other.handle) == u64::MAX }
    }
}
```

PS. I used the comments in [this file](https://github.com/project-everest/hacl-star/blob/master/dist/gcc-compatible/Hacl_Bignum4096.h), which seems to be the library in question.

Comment: Thank you I started with something like this, but I can't recall why I abandoned that approach. I do need to read up on Drop, as we need to libc::free(handle) at the right times to avoid memory leaks.